# MaterialContainerTransform: Skipping due to null end bounds. Ensure end view is laid out and measured

Tags: java, android, material-design

I´m using MaterialContainerTransform to add motion to my floating action button in my fragment. The problem is that the MaterialContainerTransform does not recognize my container which has the views that I'm trying to show after user clicks on fab.
When fab is clicked just a white screen is shown.

This is my fragment_motion.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/containerMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MotionFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewEnd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/containerBar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/error_color"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_close"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextAppearance.MyTheme.Headline5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="Settings"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btnCancel"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/containerBar" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/viewStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_filter_list" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and this is my MotionFragment.java:

```
package com.example.material;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;
import androidx.transition.TransitionManager;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.transition.MaterialContainerTransform;

public class MotionFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private FloatingActionButton viewStart;
    private CoordinatorLayout containerMain;
    private ConstraintLayout viewEnd;

    public MotionFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL,
                com.google.android.material.R.style.ShapeAppearanceOverlay_MaterialComponents_MaterialCalendar_Window_Fullscreen);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_motion, container, false);

        viewStart = view.findViewById(R.id.viewStart);
        containerMain = view.findViewById(R.id.containerMain);
        viewEnd = view.findViewById(R.id.containerBar);

        viewStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MaterialContainerTransform transform = new MaterialContainerTransform();

                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.btnCancel:
                        break;
                    case R.id.viewStart:
                        transform.setStartView(viewStart);
                        transform.setEndView(viewEnd);
                        transform.addTarget(viewEnd);

                        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(containerMain, transform);
                        viewStart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        viewEnd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```